# Linux current directory list display

Tags: linux, ls

I know how to list contents of the current directory with one entry per line using this command:
$ ls -1
However, i don't know how to simultaneously display the contents one screen at a time. I've tried using the less command but i haven't had any success so far.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: How about `ls -1|less`? Without you telling us what you're trying to achieve, what you've tried and how it fails it's hard to help.

Comment: Another variant `ls -1 | more`

Comment: thanks :) that works fine. I'm very new to linux, and i was experimenting with content display